# Ubuntu server permission troubles

Tags: server, permissions

I am currently having some permission troubles on a Ubuntu server, the problem I am currently having is allowing other users to edit and save files created by myself or for me to edit and save files created by other users.

Would it be possible to;

1. Add users to a group
2. Give each user the same permissions
3. Allow each user to edit and save the other users files

In this instance I'm not sure what is best practice and whats best for security measures.

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct answer to the problem, this might be worth considering.

If you have multiple people in a position where they can all edit the same files, it's only a matter of time before you clash and overwrite the wrong stuff, delete something somebody was working on.

I would strongly recommend moving the editing side of things to `git`. Everybody checks-out a copy of the data and commit back their changes. Merges detect conflicts and you can take sensible, *conscious* actions to remedy them. Then, on the server —if we assume this is something that is running, like a website—  checkout from the git repo under a single user.

You can work on scripting this with hooks and things like Fabric. Automating it opens the door to other nice things like testing and coverage testing; techniques and habits that help you avoid pushing bad code onto a server.

Comment: Hi Oli, thank you for your answer, I will certainly look into git and automation for larger future projects. At the moment this is really more of a learning exercise with 2 (maybe 3) people maximum. It will involve only a few files.